# How to send a gitlab backup message

Tags: gitlab

Is there a possibility to send a email notification when gitlab backup is done?
I run the backups automatically with a cronjob

[image]

Comment: `cron` sends mail by default if your job outputs anything. What does your `crontab` look like and is the machine where you run this configured to send email to the world?

Comment: gitlab is running in a docker container. how can I test mail function

Comment: Without a lot more details about where you want to send the message and how your ISP currently wants you to configure outgoing email, we can only tell you to google these things.

Comment: Also, please don't post perfectly good text as  images.